What are the character limitations of a subject name in the confluent schema registry?
What are the limiations of subject names within the Confluent schema registry?
In particular I would like to know:

What is the maximum character limit for a subject name?

I ask because the TopicRecordNameStrategy could potentially lead to very long subject names.


Does the name have to follow a specific character set (ASCII/UTF8)?
Can it start with a number?
Any other limitations with the name which should be known?

For reference: I asked the same question but for the AWS glue schema registry here.

I don't see any documentation around this but the error message from Confluent goes like this - ": invalid name for CLASSIFICATION.  Names must consist of a letter followed by a sequence of letter, number, space, or _ characters"
